# Can I output the data to a datatable in my case?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura, list, datatable

I have a `datatable` in which I want to display the data in a certain way, namely:
I have an `Exchange_Rate__c` object that has certain currency rates as fields: `USD__c, CAD__c, EUR__c, GBP__c`, as well as a `Date__c` field that displays the date when the currency rates were loaded from the external `API`.

In the table, I need to get 3 columns: `Currency, Exchange Rate, Date`. In the `Currency` field, I need to display the name of all my object fields, in the `Exchange Rate` field , the rate of the corresponding currency, and in the `Date` field, the date.

And now I don't understand how I can do it...

I get data from the database using the `apex` method and add it to my component in the list as follows: `{"Date__c":"2021-05-28","GBP__c":1,"CAD__c":1.714795,"EUR__c":1.164868,"USD__c":1.419765,"Id":"a005e000002zrh5AAA"}`

**//cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="CurrencyExchangeController">
<aura:handler action="{!c.doInit}" name="init" value="{!this}"/>
<aura:attribute name="listRecordsExchangeRates" type="Exchange_Rate__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
<lightning:datatable     keyField="computedId"
                         columns="{!v.columns}"
                         data="{!v.listRecordsExchangeRates}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**//js**

```
({
    
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set('v.columns', [
        { label: "Currency", fieldName: "currency" },
        { label: "Exchange Rate", fieldName: "exchangeRate" },
        { label: "Date", fieldName: "exchangeDate" }
    ]);
    helper.getDataFromDB(component, helper);
    }
})
```

**//helper**

```
({
    
    getDataFromDB : function(component, helper){
        let action = component.get('c.getListExchangeRates');
            action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        let state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            /**JSON.stringify(returnValue) = [{"Date__c":"2021-05- 28","Base_Currency__c":"GBP","GBP__c":1,"CAD__c":1.714795,"EUR__c":1.164868,"USD__c":1.419765,"Id":"a005e000002zwmtAAA"},{"Date__c":"2021-05-29","Base_Currency__c":"GBP","GBP__c":1,"CAD__c":1.713786,"EUR__c":1.163787,"USD__c":1.41895,"Id":"a005e00000305KhAAI"}]*/
                let returnValue = response.getReturnValue();
                let currencies = ["GBP__c","CAD__c","EUR__c","USD__c"];
                let data = currencies.map(
                (currency) => returnValue.map((record) => ({
                computedId: `${currency}-${record.Id}`,
                currency: currency.replace('__c',''),
                exchangeRate: record[currency],
                exchangeDate: record.Date__c,
                Id
              }))
            ).flat();
            component.set("v.listRecordsExchangeRates", data);
            }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

I didn't get anything in the table...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you want to do it server-side, which is certainly an option, you can write it as a relatively simple client-side action.

First, we have to compute the ID, because the record Id won't be unique in our case. We're going to have to change each record into several rows.

[image: Example Table]

That means we're going to change the markup to look like:

```
<lightning:datatable     keyField="computedId"
                         columns="{!v.columns}"
                         data="{!v.listRecordsExchangeRates}"/>
```

Next, we simply need to map the data as we like.

```
let returnValue = result.getReturnValue();
let currencies = ["GBP__c","CAD__c","EUR__c","USD__c"];
// For each currency
let data = currencies.map(
  // For each record
  (currency) => returnValue.map((record) => ({
    // Calculate a unique Id
    computedId: `${currency}-${record.Id}`,
    // Take off the __c at the end
    currency: currency.replace('__c',''),
    // Get the appropriate exchange rate (e.g. GBP__c)
    exchangeRate: record[currency],
    // And the exchange date
    exchangeDate: record.Date__c,
    // And the Id, if you need to know it
    recordId: record.Id
  }))
// We now have an Array of Arrays, so we flatten with flat()
).flat();
component.set("v.listRecordsExchangeRates", data);
```

I wrote this [as a LWC](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/NjDaN2Y822kbV9hhLko0/src/app.js) to give you an idea of what it would look like, and I've included the basic Aura you need above, it's just a matter of plugging this into the callback function (I presumed the callback is `function(result) {...}`).

Comment: I edited my code based on your answer, but I probably missed something. My table is empty...

Comment: @uniqueuser That's weird. Updated the example using the literal data you provided, it still works. I did make a small change in my code, but it's probably immaterial to your situation. Try using the new edit, though, maybe it's a "undefined variable" error. You may want to try debugging using the F12 debugger tools to see what's wrong. Also, try logging `data` to the console to see what it looks like.

Comment: Wow! Now it works! Apparently this is your change affected: `recordId: record.Id`. Thank you so much!

Comment: @uniqueuser Glad to help!